# settings for VNC viewer on win-10 to remote desktop (Win-10) by using a raspi as proxy gateway

Tags: proxy, raspberry-pi3, remote-desktop, vnc-viewer

I'm trying to access my remote desktop (win-10) from my laptop (win-10) using Raspi-3 as a proxy gateway.
I've installed tiger VNC on the remote desktop. I can access it directly from my laptop by using VNC viewer but I got stuck while accessing the remote desktop by using a proxy server. What additional setup or changes do I need to get it?
Do I need to make some changes in Squid files or need to give some additional permission to Raspi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the  Squid conf file (/etc/squid/squid.conf)-->

> `acl safe_ports port 5900`

# 5900 is default port used by VNC viewer

> http_access allow safe_ports

in VNC viewer's proxy-->
use 3128 port for diverting traffic through proxy # 3128 is default port used by Squid